# Write Operation Result In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can successfully read from a file. However, I can't get an operation results to write.

For ex.:

**i edited to include the full code with a recommended change**

```
if 5:
 from pathlib import Path
 a = Path(r"C:\Users\l\Desktop\a.txt").read_text()
 a = int(a)
 qqa = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~'
 def x(qqc, qqd):
   qqe = []
   while qqc > 0:
     qqf = qqc % qqd
     qqe.append(qqf)
     qqc = qqc // qqd
   qqg = []
   while qqe:
     qqg.append(qqa[qqe.pop()])
   return ''.join(qqg)
 b = open(r"C:\Users\l\Desktop\b.txt","w")
 b.write(str(x(a,12)))
```

To explain this:

```
a.txt contains only the string “24” (excluding the quotes)
x is a base-10 to base-_ conversion operation
“12” is the base
```

I don't want the write operation to write the literal operation “x(a,12)” (excluding the quotes).

I want the write operation to write the result “20” (excluding the quotes). (“24” in base-12 is “20”.)

How can I get this to work properly in Python 3?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Incidentally, what is `is 5`?

Comment: The actual contents of your `x()` function would appear to be the single most important detail to your question - yet you have chosen to omit it completely.  Or is the actual question how to write that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are getting 
`TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int` 
All you have to do is cast the int to str
`b.write(str(x(a,12)))`

Comment: · i tried this, but it just prints "2" in the console · i edited my post to include your recommendation in my code · also, here's a quick video of me doing the whole process: https://www.dropbox.com/s/13v7niqlb67y4k6/python.mp4?dl=0

Comment: @abcjme, 2 is the expected result of the `.write()` call, which returns the number of characters that were written.  Have you actually looked at the file, to see if the right two characters were written to it?

Comment: @jasonharper edit: nevermind, i had a simple typo · it's working now

Comment: @Bikram Shrestha nevermind, i had a simple typo · it's working now · thanks

Answer (score 1):

write() argument must be a string, so in a simple way:

```
b.write(str(x(a,12)))
```